# How to supply password at runtime to a dataset?

Tags: passwords, dataset, connection-string

I have a database with password.
If I allow the password to be saved with connectionstring it would be visible in .config file.

How can I set the same at runtime?

Checked :

[Point ADO.Net DataSet to different databases at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121350/point-ado-net-dataset-to-different-databases-at-runtime)

[Changing dataset connection string at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477544/changing-dataset-connection-string-at-runtime)

But need some way to change the connectionstring in setting itself to avoid changes at many locations.

Update: This is windows forms application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by overriding following property.
Steps.

1. Go to settings
2. Click on View Code
3. In view code add following code

Vb,Net

```
Default Public Overrides Property Item(ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
    Get
        If propertyName = "MyConnectionString" Then
            Return MyBase.Item(propertyName) & ";Password=Yourpassword;"
        End If
        Return MyBase.Item(propertyName)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        MyBase.Item(propertyName) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

C# (Rough code converted using code converter)

```
public override object this[string propertyName] {
    get {
        if (propertyName == "MyConnectionString") {
            return base.Item(propertyName) + ";Password=Yourpassword;";
        }
        return base.Item(propertyName);
    }
    set { base.Item(propertyName) = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a `DataSet`, I am using the following code:

```
myDataSet myData = new myDataSet();

myDataSetTableAdapters.myTableAdapter myInfo =
    new myDataSetTableAdapters.myTableAdapter();

myInfo.Connection.ConnectionString += ";Password=myPassword";
myInfo.Fill(myData.Info);
```

You are free to set up any part of the tableAdapters ConnectionString.

Answer (score 0):

Functional C# code, just tested (based on the brilliant answer by @Sachin Chavan). The override has to be placed in your Settings.cs file:

```
public override object this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        if (propertyName == "nameOfYourConnectionStringProperty")
        {
            return base[propertyName].ToString().Replace("******", "Y0uRpA$sW0rD");
        }
        return base[propertyName];
    }
    set { base[propertyName] = value; }
}
```