# Why does the Apache Foundation release two build tools (Ant and Maven)?

Tags: java, apache, maven, ant, build

I have experience with Ant but not with Maven.
My question is: Why does the Apache Foundation release two build tools (Ant and Maven)?

1. **Why can't the same Ant tool be upgraded to Maven?**
2. **What is the benefit of using Maven over Ant or vice versa?**
3. **What made to build Maven when Ant works as build tool?**

Comment: @downvoters give reason behind downvoting

Comment: Reason question is being voted for closure: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Comment: Recommending reading about being down voted: [I've just been down voted. How should I react to this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/121350/152134)

Answer (score 8):

Apache isn't really a "vendor", it's a foundation that hosts and supports open source projects that (in many cases) other people/groups donate to them.

The first release of Ant was back in 2000, so it's a pretty old tool. Maven was an attempt to handle building a project in different ways. It doesn't make any sense to decommission Ant as it still has a lot of value.

Answer (score 3):

Just because something is working doesn't mean that it can't be improved upon.
ANT itself was built as a pure java alternative to MAKE.
See [What is ANT](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#what-is-ant) for the philosophy behind ANT.
Also look at [What is maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) for the Maven teams take on what the goals of maven are.

Personally I draw a lot of value from the dependency management capabilities of maven.

Answer (score 1):

The best build tool is the one you write yourself. Every project’s build process is unique, and often individual projects need to be built multiple different ways.
If you don’t want to write your own build tool, then you should use: Ant or Maven
Ant is a build tool; Maven is a build system:

What this means is that with Maven, you don't need to decide your directory layout, build targets, versioning scheme, management of dependencies, etc. This is all designed for you. It also means you will be working against the tool somewhat if you don't like the default.

The benefits are that most of the common tools you want to build into your build system (CheckStyle, FindBugs, Unit Testing, Unit Coverage, JDepened...) are all available without any additional development work. In addition, there is a well-defined framework for extending the build system by building plugins (btw - using Ant to build plugins is trivially easy). Also, there is nice integration with IDEs so that developers are using the same build information as the auto-build system.

The trade-off is that unless you are starting from scratch, you will probably need to refactor your source code to be in line with what Maven expects. The trade-off for not having to build everything from scratch is that you sometimes spend time figuring out how to coax Maven to do what you want, how you want it done.

Comment: "The best build tool is the one your write yourself".... Really? Not meaning to be insulting, but there are already too many build tools for Java :-)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor To be out of respect is not the point here. Some people are born with these super powers, and can put minimal effort to express their ideas.